# Is there a way to default restore the Basic-Decks?

Tags: hearthstone

I never felt like needing more then 9 deckslots.
But now as they're there I guess I'm going to use them.

But I really liked the basic decks to introduce new players to the game.
Since my ladder decks would just vaporize their decks.

And when I sometimes made lite versions of my decks, even 1 or 2 epics had been enough to make my opponent complain about unfair cards. So basic decks where the best way for fair playing.

But when I'm now able to delete those without a way of restoring the basic decks, I'd prefer to not use these slots at all, since I don't want to start googling and recreate a basic deck by hand when needed.

So is there an ingame feature to rebuild the basic decks?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The basic decks don't "go away" - they just aren't viewable in the deck builder.

Comment: @twobugs: Blizzard posted in their patch notes that the 9 additional slots are available if I edit/delete the basic decks. So I assumed my additional decks are the pre-basic decks. Is this asumption wrong? so now I have effectively 27 decks available and not as previous just 18?

Comment: I haven't seen these patch notes, but on the current version of Hearthstone you're still able to use your basic decks if you go to the play menu. At the bottom where it says "Custom decks" there is an arrow, and hitting that switches to basic decks. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @twobugs: this is still after you ahve overwritten the additonal 9 slots? Where do you select them then?

Comment: it says(http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/20054739/hearthstone-patch-notes-420-14-03-2016): "If you’ve already unlocked all nine Heroes, your new deck slots are waiting for you in the Collection Manager: just delete or edit the Basic decks you’ll find in your deck list."

Comment: Hm, my iPad app hadn't auto-updated. Interesting. I'll play around and see if I can some up with something.

Comment: Fwiw, "basic" is a valid keyword for the card collection filter. You can use it to quickly build a basic deck - it matches all the basic cards and Finley

Comment: @blgt: Yeah but I have no motivation doing so, cause this would just be crap(ish). So the basic decks have 2 advantages: 1) using them vs. creating own "basic decks" in the second case, I can't resist putting 2 or 3 of my favorite cards in which aren't usefull in meta and so I didn't use long time. But those 2-3 cards are enough to make the match imballanced and unfair. 2) In case I just start using this deck slots I would not again remove one of my usefull meta decks to just put together some random basic crap and even sepnt concentraion for the selection. Simply something I won't do anymore.

Comment: Can't you just use one of the new deck recipes, and then swap out the big bad legendaries for something less competetive?

Comment: @freekvd: I could, but thats exactly the problem. first: when I try to bring some one into the game and I do nice devistating moves they are gonna ask what cards that had been, and it is contra productive if you then say "you need money or luck to get these cards" On the other hand I'm just too undisciplinated to spent time in building a deck and keep just picking those boring cards the neby can use aswell. Because I get so many funny ideas I could never try in a ranked game, but here it would be funny but ok.... and is ending devastating in the end anyway...

Comment: @freekvd: but the standard decks where perfect at this point since I had to invest no time or deckslots for making a fair game and also wasn't exposed to the temptation of picking more rare cards. But I actually ended in not using the additional 9 slots and keep restricting my self to the usual 9 slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.
Go [here](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Basic_deck) and just copy the hash, when you go to make the deck it will automatically ask you if you want to build the deck from the clipboard, then it's done.

Answer (score 3):

No, currently there's no way to rebuild the basic decks.
With patch 4.2 the 9 additional deck slots we're getting are taking the place of the old basic decks. Once you remove the old decks, they're gone, so if you want to play again with them you'll have to keep them saved or write the cards up to rebuild them in the future.